# How to insert data from databse to JTable using 4 tier

Tags: java, swing, jtable, derby

Here's what I encountered

UI:

```
       jlbl.setText("Purchase ID: ");
   String counterV = String.valueOf(purc.getCounter());

   jTF3.setText("P000"+counterV);
   JPanel p5 = new JPanel();
    p5.add(jlbl);
   p5.add(jTF3);

  else if(e.getSource() == jbtRetrieve)
        {

            String pID = jTF3.getText();
        Purchase purchase = purcControl.selectRecord(pID);
        if (purchase != null) {
            String pdCountStr = purchase.getPurchaseDetailsID();
            String pdCountStr2 = pdCountStr.substring(2,6);
            int pdCount = Integer.parseInt(pdCountStr2);
            for(int g = 0; g<pdCount;g++)
            tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{ purchase.getPurchaseDetailsID(),purchase.getStockID(),purchase.getPrice(),purchase.getQuantity()});

        }
        else {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No such purchase ID.", "RECORD NOT FOUND", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);


        }
        }
```

Control :

```
    public Purchase selectRecord(String pID){
    return purcDA.getRecord(pID);
}
```

DA :

```
 public Purchase getRecord(String pID){
    String queryStr = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE PurchaseID = ?";
    Purchase purchase = null;
    //MainPurchasingFrame purc = new MainPurchasingFrame();

    try{
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(queryStr);
        stmt.setString(1,pID);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();



     if(rs.next()){
        purchase = new Purchase(rs.getString("purchaseDetailsID"),pID, ,rs.getString("stockID"),rs.getDouble("price"),rs.getInt("quantity"));
     }
    }   catch (SQLException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex.getMessage(),"ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    return purchase;
}
```

Domain:

```
 public String getPurchaseDetailsID(){

    return purchaseDetailsID ;

}
public double getPrice(){
    return price;
}
public String getStockID(){
    return stockID;
}
public int getQuantity(){
    return quantity;
}
public void setPurchaseDetailsID(String r){
    this.purchaseDetailsID = r ;
}
public void setPrice(double p){
    this.price = p;
}
public void setStockID(String s){
    this.stockID = s;
}
public void setQuantity(int q){
    this.quantity = q;
}
```

How do I enter my data into JTable through 4 tier like this ? I know how to do it when everything is set in one but I face `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException` 
everytime I trying to retrieve data. I'm using netbean.

Comment: What line does the NPE point to? It should give you some idea of where you should be looking.

Comment: its pointing  Purchase purchase = purcControl.selectRecord(pID); where I dnno what's the problem.

Comment: Then you have to figure out why `purcControl` is null. We can't do that, as you have not provided the necessary code

Comment: I tried but, I've set values to the purchase plus if it is null shudn't it run the else part ?

Comment: If you try to perform an operation (`selectRecord(pID)`) on a null object (`purcControl`), you will get a NPE. As we can't see where the `purcControl` is declared and instantiated, we can't help you find the problem. So you need to find out why it is null

Comment: See [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I just simply declare it as private MaintainPurchasingControl purcControl

Comment: And where does it get instantiated/initialized?

Comment: It was never initialized. As I declare it just to call the mainpurchasingcontrol part where it will links to DA part

Comment: You **can't** call any methods on a object that hasn't been initialized.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the error, cause I really can't find it = =

Answer (score 0):

```
purcControl = new MaintainPurchasingControl();
```

to initialize the purcControl so NPE will not happen.